# moving select or radio element in DOM loses selected value

Tags: jquery

I am moving an entire form from one div to another then moving it back. On the move back using

```
jQuery('.orig-div').prepend(jQuery('.temp-div ').html());
```

some elements (select and radio) lose their value. Why is that happening?

The first move uses avgrund overlay which does this:

```
var $popin = $('<div class="avgrund-popin temp-div"></div>');
$popin.append(popinContent);
body.append($popin);
popinContent.show();
```

And popinContent is the form element (ie form.formclass)

Comment: Care to show us what exactly you are doing?

Comment: Yeah I realized I needed more detail as soon as I hit send but you were fast on the draw...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `.html()`, that just gets the HTML source code of the elements, it loses their state. Append the elements themselves rather than the HTML.

```
jQuery('.orig-div').prepend(jQuery('.temp-div').contents());
```

Comment: Many thanks @Barmar. I knew it was something technical I was screwing up.